# I'm new to starting a server on my own. I need advice on what to do

Tags: boot

I would like to start my own server, but I don't know how. I would like advice on what to do. My server would be a public one, and it will always be on. I would use Static IP for my server.

Comment: Public server. Always on. What is Static IP or Dynamic?

Comment: What will it serve? Are you prepared to learn server administration and security? What research have you already done? AskUbuntu works best with very specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using VMware or the free Virtual Box is a great option for learning.  If you can't snapshot your VM instance, you can at least copy the VM image and always restore it before trying out changes using the copy of the VM image you took before tinkering with it.

I also like playing with hardware, so if you have any old equipment (computer) lying around, you can install Ubuntu server there.  The install is pretty well automated, so you shouldn't experience too many problems.  I find that for beginners, not familiar with virtual networking, a physical machine may serve as a good platform to learn on as you should have access to the both the terminal (the machine) and if you install ssh server, remote access to work on the server as well.

Next, download the LTS version of Ubuntu server and burn it disk (if you have a DVD writer (and reader on the destination hardware), or USB.  Turn the computer on and let it boot to the disk or USB drive.

If you go virtual (VMware, Virtual Box), you just need to download the ubuntu server ISO to a directory on your machine.  On VMware, File > New Virtual Machine - choose custome, tell it to use ISO and point to where you downloaded the ISO image; It may let you use easy install where it knows all the prompts, just give it a username, name, and password, name the machine/image, choose number of processors (just select 1 processor), and number of cores per processor (I'd do 2 to start of with - you can increase it later, also depends on your system, don't take more than 75% of your available cores of your own system - ie., if you have Core i7, 4 cores, 8 threads, don't give the VM more than 6 cores), for memory, again, leave yourself a min. of 6-8 GB for your host, and try to give the server at least 4 GB to start off with.  Again, you can add more later if needed.  You can use Briged networking, or NAT, but with NAT, requires you to do some virtual networking to remotely access the server or access it locally via VMware (easy to do), but with bridged, it should be given an IP which you can then use to access both remotely and via Vmware), for drive, choose the default SCSI controller (LSI Logic), choose SCSI for the disk (remember, these are virtual, it doesn't mean you have to have these to make this work), create a new virtual disk, for Ubuntu server, 20GB is plenty, I prefer to keep the virtual disk as a single file versus multiple, either will work fine, name the disk file (same as machine the VM name you gave it earlier is a good way to go), Click Finish, and away you go.

I know Virtual Box, but I have that on my VB server, and it's down for maintenance, so I can't give you the exact steps, but same concept - create, assign cpu, mem, disk, point it to the iso, and away you go, but VB normally you have no automated approach to setup, so go through the ISO.  If you blow it, or make a mistake, let it finish, delete the VM instance, and start over - easy :)

Once setup, you can login via VMware or Virtual Box console by double clicking on the VM to start it, Then you get the login prompt in the VMware or VB console, or you can login remotely with it's IP address (if you chose Bridged mode for networking) and you get a login prompt.  Enter your username you gave during setup and the password, and congratulations, you are in Linux Server world, welcome aboard :)

Comment: Okay. I will take the time to read this through and kill my eyes in the process.

Comment: Sorry - was trying to be as brief/helpful as possible.

Comment: No, you're fine. This is actually very helpful. I'm gonna do this. What do you recommend for server starters?

Comment: My first personal server, was Ubuntu Server.  Since you are asking, I'm assuming that's where you are now.  For virtual, you can download Virtual Box (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) free, or VMware player for free (https://www.vmware.com/products/workstation-player/workstation-player-evaluation.html).  I like both of them, but feel VirtualBox is more user friendly.  Both are well known virtualization options, so no need to worry about is it safe.  I like that virtual box maintains support for older operating systems, and has a bigger support community.  So I'd go with Virtualbox.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. This will help me.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to use a VM manager like vmware. Create a VM on it, install Ubuntu and start learning. Read articles, books, etc related to what you wanna do on your server and apply it on the VM to get used to it.

Some VM managers have snapshot feature that allows us to create a snapshot before trying something and then quickly bring it back before. This helps to revert any mistake we make. You can also use any partition backup tool that supports ext4 and maybe SMB or FTP.

You can also create a virtual network of several VMs, so you can provide clients to your server.